# Monitoring request headers sent by Node.js

Tags: node.js, reddit

So I'm working on a service that calls a subreddit and requests the hottest articles in JSON. Now Reddit likes that anyone using the reddit API modifies their User-Agent Header to be descriptive (here's [a link](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) on the format).

So using Node.JS and the [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) plugin, I wrote something like this

```
var subreddit = 'somesupercoolsubreddit';
var stories = '5';
var options ={
    url : url.parse(REDDIT_URL+"/r/"+subreddit+"/hot.json"+"?"+"limit="+stories),
    headers : {'User-Agent' :  'Super Cool Reddit Service for Local Widgets! by /u/mrkaiser'}, 
    json: true
};
request(options,function(err,response,body){
    serverResponse.send(body);
});
```

But how do I know this worked? Is there some way to know if request header actually got populated or if Reddit got the right User-Agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another node script that waits for connections and outputs the headers. Change your reddit script to temporarily call the new script and verify the headers.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the same node.js script?